# QObject::connect failing with inheritance (no such slot, but Q_OBJECT macro defined)

Tags: c++, qt

My problem is best described by looking at some pseudo-code:

**Headers:**

```
class A: public QWidget
{
  Q_OBJECT

  public:
    void setupUserInterface(...);
    void funcA(...);
    void funcB(...);

  // etc..
}

class B: public A {
  Q_OBJECT

  // etc..
}
```

**Implementation:**

```
void A::setupUserinterface(...) // uiel1, uiel2 as input
{
  connect(uiel1, SIGNAL(pressed()), this, SLOT(funcA()));
  connect(uiel2, SIGNAL(pressed()), this, SLOT(funcB()));
}

void A::funcA(...) { ... }
void A::funcB(...) { ... }
```

When I try to build and run, I get the following errors:

```
QObject::connect: No such slot B::funcA in /.../A.cpp
QObject::connect: No such slot B::funcB in /.../A.cpp
```

Meaning that for some reason, it is looking for B-members in A.cpp.

How can I solve this? Thanks in advance.

**Update 1:**
Making the functions `funcA` and `funcB` `virtual` does not help.

Comment: Your `funcA` and `funcB` are not actually defined as slots... Is that a typo?

Comment: You have to declare `funcA()` and `funcB()` as slots under `slots:` specifier in the class A

Comment: Do people not read the documentation anymore? http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html#signals-and-slots

Comment: @cmannett85 People do, but people also overlook. My apologies. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `funcA` and `funcB` are not actually slots. This is the correct way:

```
class A: public QWidget
{
  Q_OBJECT

  public://just public methods
    void setupUserInterface(...);

  public slots://slots declarations section
    void funcA(...);
    void funcB(...);
}
```

Comment: Darn. That was easy. I was always told that putting "slots" in the header was just for readability. This solves it. Thanks.